# Resetting Eclipselink JPA Entity manager after failure

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am currently having some trouble with my JPA Entity manager (Using Eclipselink).
Whenever something goes wrong in the Entity manager, I am no longer able to do anything with it. I have to restart every time. This is really anoying and when thinking about using this in production, I don't really feel confortable about this.

Is there some was to reset the Entity manager without having to restart the entire application? Are there some config-options allowing me to make the entity manager a little more robust against failling jpa operations?

Chris

Comment: You are using application-managed or container-managed entity manager?

Comment: It's an application-managed context.

Comment: em.clear() cleares the persistence context it manages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when any exception is thrown by the EntityManager, it has to be discarded as it becomes unusable (usually throwing IllegalStateException on any operation except `close()`).

I've never tried what JMelnik suggest as I always use a container-managed context, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details,

"Whenever something goes wrong" - what goes wrong?  What error do you get, include the stack.

"I am no longer able to do anything" - What error do you get?

In general when an operation fails with an EntityManager, you just close it and create a new one from the factory.  EntityManagers should be used per request, or per transaction, so getting a new one should not be an issue, unless you have a bad application design.

You can also call clear() to reset a specific EntityManager to continue to use it.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter what type of JPA error occured. Forreign Key Constraint failure, Too large values, null values in non-null fields, ... No matter what goes wrong. After that I can't use the entityManager any more. I would have expected the entityManager of a running transaction to be corrupted, but it seems to effect all usages of an entityManager even in other spring components.

Comment: Would it be possible that Spring injects the same PersistenceContext into every Spring bean and as soon as one does something wrong all of them are corrupted as they reference the same instance? ... I would have expected the entity manager to be cleaned up after the process leaves the @Transactional method that initialized the transaction, but it doesn't seem to be that way.

Comment: I think I'm simply switching back to hibernate. I can't see a reason why an entity manager encountering an exception in one request should affect other threads servicing completely different requests.